# Pageant seem to have interference, does not work at all

Tags: putty, public-key-encryption, pageant

I have a server setup with my public key and adding my private key to putty allows me to connect to the server properly. When I use pageant however, it doesn't work. My research showed that the event log with pageant running should look something like:

> ....
>   Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
>   Pageant has X SSH-2 keys
>   Trying Pageant key #0
>   ....

however, my event log looks like

> ...
>   Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
>   ...

It seems like pageant isn't responding to putty's key request. Any help in this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing this too, with snapshot r9169 (fixes lots of win7 bugs) but it worked ok with putty v0.60.

Comment: I had the same problem. The problem has been resolved by installing the latest snapshot of Putty via http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/x86/putty.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like if you have a default private key configured like this guy did

[image]

Then it can break the pageant keys, it simply doesn't try to use them!

`plink -v root@xx.xx.xx.xx` fails

```
Reading private key file "D:\.ssh\id_rsa.ppk"
Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Pageant has 1 SSH-2 keys
Configured key file not in Pageant
Using username "root".
Offered public key
Server refused our key
Server refused our key
```

`plink -v -i x root@xx.xx.xx.xx` which disables the default key

```
Unable to use key file "x" (unable to open file)
Pageant is running. Requesting keys.
Pageant has 1 SSH-2 keys
Using username "root".
Trying Pageant key #0
Authenticating with public key "key.pem" from agent
```

You need to see Trying Pageant key #0, #1 ,#2 etc

Comment: this was `plink: Release 0.62`